# C++ pointer array initialization help

Tags: c++

I had trouble with initializing arrays of pointers. What I found out compiling with gcc c++ (4.6.0) is:

```
MyClass** a = new MyClass*[100];
```

Does not always initalize the array of pointers. (most of the time it did give me an array of null pointers which confused me)

```
MyClass** a = new MyClass*[100]();
```

DOES initialize all the pointers in the array to 0 (null pointer).

The code I'm writing is meant to be be portable across Windows/Linux/Mac/BSD platforms. Is this a special feature of the gcc c++ compiler? or is it standard C++?  Where in the standard does it says so?

Comment: Presumably you mean `MyClass** a = new MyClass*[100]()`. Yes, the `new` initializer is a standard feature. I'm just hunting down a duplicate question.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate because it asks why not (which is incorrect) rather than why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717246/no-array-allocated-using-new-can-have-an-initializer ... but close enough. Voting to close.

Comment: The first version returns uninitialized memory, which of course *can* be NULL (zero) if it is previously unused. Most OSs clear out memory allocated to a process, for security reasons.

Comment: Duplicate of [Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new)

Comment: It not a duplication because this question asks for references to the C++ standard.

Comment: Thanks John for fixit it and Charles for pointing out the duplicate.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, nor a precise opposite. If anything, it's more an extension to those questions (they both ask why or how, this is "what does the spec say given the why and how?").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This value-initialization is standard C++.

The relevant standardeese is in C++98 and C++03 §5.3.4/15. In C++98 it was default-initialization, in C++03 and later it's value initialization. For your pointers they both reduce to zero-initialization.

C++03 §5.3.4/15:

> > – If the *new-initializer* is of the form `()`, the item is value-initialized (8.5);

In C++0x that paragraph instead refers to “the initialization rules of 8.5 for direct-initialization”, where in N3290 (the FDIS) you find about the same wording in §8.5/16.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Great answer! Exaclty what I was hoping for. I can now default/value/zero initialize with confidence.